# save multiple key/value pairs to app.config

Tags: c#, app-config, key-value

I'm working on an winform application, where I store some setting (username, email, zipcode) in the app.config file.

```
public static void Set(string key, string value)
    {

        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        var entry = config.AppSettings.Settings[key];
        if (entry == null)
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
        else
            config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
```

I'd like to save the settings to the app.config file. So I have this code.
Problem is: I can only use the variable key once.... So i can't saven the email and zipcode.
I was thinking of working with an array, but I have no idea on how to implement this. Any suggestions?

```
private void button_savesettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string key = "username";
        string username = textBox_user.Text;

        Set(key, username);

        

    }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop will solve the problem

```
void SetAppSettingsValues(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    // bit of validation
    if (dict == null || !dict.Any())
        return;

    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
    {
        var configItem = config.AppSettings.Settings[key];

        if (configItem == null)
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, dict[key].Value);
        else
            config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = dict[key].Value;
    }

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: The name 'Key' does not excist in the current context. It's about these 2 'Key's: config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, dict[Key].Value);
        else
            config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = dict[Key].Value;

Comment: It was a capitalization problem. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use SQLite for Winform.
Saving things to app.config could be messy when your data variable grows bigger.